# Match object coordinates with image coordinates

Tags: 3d, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I am new to Unreal and I want to accomplish a task.

I have an image with different hand poses. For each image I have the center 3D coordinates and the (roll, pitch,yaw) coordinates. On the other hand; I have a 3D hand object in Unreal. I want to mimic the position and orientation of the hand in the image to the 6D coordinates in unreal.

Basically; given the 6D coordinates of the hand pose in the image; the object when it is in the same position and orientation as the image; the 6D coordinates in unreal should be similar to the image coordinates.